# Split my dataset in train/validation using MapDataset in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

Hi everyone I'm facing an issue after that I elaborate images and labels. To create an unique dataset I use the zip function. After the elaboration both images and labels are 18k and it's correct but when I call the zip(image,labels), items become 563.
Here some code to let you to understand:

```
# Map the load_and_preprocess_image function over the dataset of image paths
images = image_paths.map(load_and_preprocess_image)
# Map the extract_label function over the dataset of image paths
labels = image_paths.map(extract_label)    
# Zip the labels and images together to create a dataset of (image, label) pairs
#HERE SOMETHING STRANGE HAPPENS
data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((images,labels))
# Shuffle and batch the data
data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(32)
# Split the data into train and test sets
data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=len(data))
# Convert the dataset into a collection of data
num_train = int(0.8 * len(data))
train_data = image_paths.take(num_train)
val_data = image_paths.skip(num_train)
```

I cannot see where is the error. Can you help me plese? Thanks

I'd like to have a dataset of 18k images,labels

Answer (score 0):

1. tf's zip

`tf.data.Dataset.zip` is not like Python's `zip`. The `tf.data.Dataset.zip`'s input is `tf datasets`. You may check the images/label return from your map function is the correct `tf.Dataset` object.

2. check tf.ds

make sure your image/label is correct tf.ds.

```
print("ele: ", images_dataset.element_spec)
print("num: ", images_dataset.cardinality().numpy())
print("ele: ", labels_dataset.element_spec)
print("num: ", labels_dataset.cardinality().numpy())
```

3. workaround

In your case, combine the image and label processing in one map function and return both to bypass to use `tf.data.Dataset.zip`:

```
# load_and_preprocess_image_and_label
def load_and_preprocess_image_and_label(image_path):
    """ load image and label then some operations """
    return image, label

# Map the load_and_preprocess_image function over the dataset of image/label paths
train_list = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(PATH / 'train/*.jpg'))
data = train_list.map(load_and_preprocess_image_and_label,
                                  num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```